# Iterating raster and extract multi value of point files using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I have several raster dataset (<8000 dataset) and one of point shapefile (contain 10 points).

I have created a model in ModelBuilder and extract it using multivalues to points feature on ArcGIS.

Can you help me to correct my model?

[image]

Are there any possibilities to create a field name on shapefile with same name as raster file?

For example I have raster file "201702022300.tiff" and on "buoy_sawu.shp" I will have an output fieldname (using multivalue to point tools) a "201702022300" field name?

Comment: i think it almost same with this problem
[link] https://geonet.esri.com/thread/101572
could any body has a better idea for my problems?

Comment: It is ***not*** possible to name fields to all-numeric names.

Comment: If you want us to correct your model, you're going to have to tell us what errors it spits back at you and what erroneous results you get—if any—when you run it.